# Unzipping files in SAS using 7zip

Tags: command-line, sas

I´m currently trying to unzip an excel file using 7zip in SAS.

I´ve done some looking around and I´ve managed to put this together although I get the error message "7-Zip: Cannot find archive"

```
%let UNZIP = C:\Users\maz\Outputfile;
%let CDRIVE = C:\Users\maz\Zip File\TodayFile.zip;

data _null_;
X "cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip"; 
X "7zG e &CDRIVE. -o&UNZIP."; 
run;
```

Doing some research tells me the folder does not exist, but I know it does. Also, some sources use 7za but I only have 7zG. Any ideas on what to look at next or what is going on?

Comment: And if you have SAS 9.4 TS1M4+ I believe you can use filename ZIP and avoid that entirely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very likely due to the space in 'Zip File'. Try putting quotes around the path name. You can use a double double-quote in a string to represent a single double-quote(!), like this:

```
X "7zG e ""&CDRIVE"" -o&UNZIP";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
X cd "C:\Program Files\7-Zip";
```

Not really a SAS question.  You need to follow the rules of the OS for a path with blanks.

Comment: Well I'm running it in SAS so I thought it would also count as a SAS question. 
the code: X "cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip"; does work fine.

Perhaps this should have been a comment, rather than you posting it as an answer.

Comment: No your CD does not work.  Open a DOS box and run this 
cd C:\Program Files\7-Zip